Implementing a Lazy Vertical Pager with Pagination in Jetpack Compose
We have implemented most of the features and we tried to use both LazyColumn and VerticalPager, our issue start from here:

using lazyColumn work and its fetching the data dynamically with the pagination in work but it does not give us the desired UI for interaction and scrolling animation effect so we started Using VerticalPager.
VerticalPager as i mentioned gives us the desired paging effect, but it does not work with the pagination, we see that when we run our app that section of the app loads all the data from our database (We have 30 document and our pagination logic is to fetch 5 item at a time, when we reach 2 item before the end we should fetch 5 more item so we will have a total of 10... and so on), we concluded that VerticalPager is not a Lazy Component and i am not sure of that.

Now we want to have the Vertical Pager Interaction with the Lazy behavior, so we can have both the pagination logic to work correctly and UI Interaction to work as instagram reels and Youtube short, how can we achieve that? or better how can we modify our code to do that?
Here is a snippet of our code and what we already tried:
Our Lazy Column which the pagination works but the UI Interaction is not what we want
LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            items(pagingVideo.itemCount) { index ->
                val news = pagingVideo[index]!!
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .padding(20.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .background(Color.Red),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                ) {
                    Text(text = news.blinkID)
                }
            }
        }

Our Vertical Pager Which have the correct UI scrolling effect as a Pager but loads all data from our Firebase
    val pagingVideo = state.videos.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    val refresh = pagingVideo.loadState.refresh
    val append = pagingVideo.loadState.append

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        pagingVideo.refresh()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(state.currentPosition) {
        interactionListener.updateSliderPosition(state.currentPosition)
    }

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
    ) { pagingVideo.itemCount }

    val fling = PagerDefaults.flingBehavior(
        state = pagerState, lowVelocityAnimationSpec = tween(
            easing = LinearEasing, durationMillis = 300
        )
    )

        VerticalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(black)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(innerPadding),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            flingBehavior = fling,
            beyondBoundsPageCount = 0,
            key = { index ->
                pagingVideo[index]?.blinkID?.let { id ->
                    if (id.isNotEmpty()) "$id-$index" else "$index"
                } ?: "$index"
            }
        ) { pagerIndex ->

            val blinks = pagingVideo[pagerIndex]!!

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                VideoPlayer(
                    blinks,
                    interactionListener,
                    pagerState,
                    pagerIndex,
                    editPlayer = { exoPlayer = it }
                )

                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = state.pauseButton,
                    enter = scaleIn(
                        spring(Spring.DampingRatioMediumBouncy),
                        initialScale = 1.3f
                    ),
                    exit = scaleOut(tween(150)),
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_blink_play),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        tint = Color.Unspecified,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(36.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pagingVideo.loadState.apply {
        when {
            refresh is LoadState.Loading -> LoadingProgressBar()
            refresh is LoadState.Error -> print(refresh)
            append is LoadState.Loading -> {
                LoadingProgressBar()
                Log.d(TAG, "BlinksScreenContent: ${pagingVideo.itemCount}")
            }

            append is LoadState.Error -> print(append)
        }
    }

Note: We are aiming to create the Instagram reels layout where we have each cell to display a portrait video when that cell appear we play that cell video and when it disappear we no longer play that video, as for the video player we used ExoPlayer.
Any help is much much appreciated.
I have added two video as better context, first video showing the vertical pager with the UI interaction that we require, the second one is the lazyColumn which have the videos but when we drag down the video the whole UI Refreshes.

Vertical Pager: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1234FiQuqSKowp7wK5kjjJ5dFgfps_pPc/view?usp=sharing

LazyColumn: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Jdl1lfMYZtH7C-wxIB4sVpcZ3iYriI7/view?usp=sharing



Can you provide any graphics of expected scrolling behavior?

@PravinDivraniya yes i have provided 2 video, check the google drive links it contain the vertical pager which is what we want and currently have but it does not support pagination as it loads all document. the second video is LazyColumn which support pagination but the UI refresh and The UI is super ugly as a result.

@RebinA.Dev May I ask you did you find any solution? I'm looking for the similar solution using VerticalPager + pagination
